# Can I view the console logs of my web app in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I'm deploying a web app in azure using the container registry I created and an auto-generated webhook. And now I want to access the **console** logs of the webapp container, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Portal, locate the Monitoring section in the App Service menu.  Select App Service Logs and enable application logging.

You can access the logs via FTP or by using the Advanced Tools.

To stream the logs, select Log Stream to stream them directly in the Portal or use the CLI in a terminal:

```
az webapp log tail --name <appname> --resource-group <resourcegroupname>
```

There's a complete [MS Learn module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/capture-application-logs-app-service/) covering this topic.